# Mutual Independence Definition Clarification

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

Let $Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_n$ be iid random variables and $B_1, B_2, ..., B_n$ be Borel sets. It follows that

$P(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} (Y_i \in B_i)) = \Pi_{i=1}^{n} P(Y_i \in B_i)$...I think?

If so, does the converse hold true? My Stochastic Calculus professor says it does (or maybe misinterpreted him somehow?), [but](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725812/mutual-independence-of-union-of-events/725826#725826) I was [under](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133646/question-about-the-independence-definition) the [impression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#More_than_two_random_variables) that independence of the n random variables was equivalent to saying for any indices $i_1, i_2, ..., i_k$ $P(\bigcap_{j=i_1}^{i_k} (Y_j \in B_j)) = \Pi_{j=i_1}^{i_k} P(Y_j \in B_j)$.

So, if the RVs are independent, then we can choose $i_j=j$ and k=n to get $P(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} (Y_i \in B_i)) = \Pi_{i=1}^{n} P(Y_i \in B_i)$, but given $P(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} (Y_i \in B_i)) = \Pi_{i=1}^{n} P(Y_i \in B_i)$, I don't know how to conclude that for any indices $i_1, i_2, ..., i_n$ $P(\bigcap_{j=i_1}^{i_k} (Y_j \in B_j)) = \Pi_{j=i_1}^{i_k} P(Y_j \in B_j)$, if that's even the right definition.

p.17 [here](http://www.tau.ac.il/~tsirel/Courses/ProbMath/A1.pdf) seems to suggest otherwise. idk

Help please?

Also this:

[image]

or

[image]

So, this answer is to use the Omega part to establish pairwise independence and ultimately conclude independence. Without that assumption, we cannot conclude independence. Is that right? Why does that not contradict the definition of independence: $P(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} (Y_i \in B_i)) = \Pi_{i=1}^{n} P(Y_i \in B_i)$ ?

Comment: How does p. 17 in your link seem to suggest otherwise?

Comment: @stefan hansen sorry unclear I meant it goes against me and supports you guys

Comment: @StefanHansen added pictures.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/924865/on-for-all-in-if-and-only-if-statements-in-probability-theory-and-stochastic-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was [under][2] the [impression][3] that independence of the n random variables was equivalent to saying for any indices $i_1, i_2, ..., i_n$ $P(\bigcap_{j=i_1}^{i_n} (Y_j \in B_j)) = \Pi_{j=i_1}^{i_n} P(Y_j \in B_j)$.

You misread: independence of $n$ random variables $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$ is equivalent to the following condition:

> (C) For every distinct indices $i_1, i_2, ..., i_k$ and every $B_j$, $P(\bigcap\limits_{j=i_1}^{i_k} (Y_j \in B_j)) = \prod\limits_{j=i_1}^{i_k} P(Y_j \in B_j)$.

Indeed, choosing $k=n$ and $i_j=j$, (C) implies condition (C'):

> (C') For every $B_j$, $P(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n} (Y_i \in B_i)) = \prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} P(Y_i \in B_i)$.

In the other direction, if (C') holds, then, for every distinct indices $i_1, i_2, ..., i_k$ and every $B_j$, one can complete the collection of events by $(Y_s\in\mathbb R)$ for the $n-k$ missing indices $s$, then (C) follows.

Comment: OMG SORRY. (C) is totally what I meant. Thanks Did. Anyway, what? Why does C' imply C? This seems to suggest otherwise. http://www.engr.mun.ca/~ggeorge/MathGaz04.pdf I mean, isn't the example what my prof was asserting?

Comment: As I said, (C) and (C') are equivalent. Note that (C) and (C') assert that some property holds *for every Borel subsets* B_i, not for some specific collection (B_i).

Comment: My prof did say something about for every $B_i$ but how is that relevant? I honestly don't get how C follows from your splitting up of k and n-k...

Comment: If $P(Y_1\in B_1,Y_2\in B_2,Y_3\in B_3,Y_4\in B_4,Y_5\in B_5)$ is what it should be for every $(B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4,B_5)$ then $P(Y_1\in B_1,Y_3\in B_3,Y_4\in B_4)$ is what it should be for every $(B_1,B_3,B_4)$ since $$P(Y_1\in B_1,Y_3\in B_3,Y_4\in B_4)=P(Y_1\in B_1,Y_2\in\mathbb R,Y_3\in B_3,Y_4\in B_4,Y_5\in\mathbb R).$$

Comment: Sorta getting it. How is that different from the link earlier though? I got it from Wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#cite_ref-3

Comment: Remember that question of mine (now deleted but temporarily deleted) from before? It went: In [David Williams' Probability with Martingales][1]

Given a probability space. Let $\mathfrak{I}_1, \mathfrak{I}_2, \mathfrak{I}_3$ be $\pi$-systems on $\Omega$ such that for k = 1, 2, 3,

$\mathfrak{I}_k \subseteq \mathfrak{F}$ and $\Omega \in \mathfrak{I}_k$

Prove that if $P( \bigcap_{i=1}^{3} I_i) = \Pi_{i=1}^{3} P(I_i)$ whenever $I_k \in \mathfrak{I}_k$ for k = 1, 2, 3, then $\sigma(\mathfrak{I}_k)$ for k = 1, 2, 3 are independent. Explain why $\Omega \in \mathfrak{I}_k$ is needed.

Comment: Yeah so I figured it out. The Omega thing is needed to establish pairwise independence and to ultimately conclude independence of the $\pi$-systems. Without it, we cannot say that the $\pi$-systems are independent right?

Comment: Did, added pictures.

Comment: Yeah, and all this is completely offtopic with respect to the question you started with, to which I fully replied.

Comment: Did, I mean, how come I can't conclude independence of the Pi-Systems right away but I can for the random variables?

Comment: Where do you see pi-systems in the definition of independence for random variables? I see only collections of sets $(Y\in B)$ with $B$ in the Borel sigma-algebra. These collections ARE SIGMA-ALGEBRAS. So, what are you talking about exactly?

Comment: Did In the Williams exercise, the probabilities splitting up does not imply independence. But for random variables it does?

Comment: READ MY COMMENT and THINK about it.

Comment: You're brilliant AND funny, Did :)) Okay fiiiiiine